# Force per velocity per time squared signifies what?

Tags: impedance

Anyone know what force per velocity per time squared signifies? It has something to do with magnetic fields.

I was doing dimensional analysis and it popped up. (Charge is given units of force and the rest just follows)

\$ E \quad = \quad \frac{q_1}{d^2}  = \quad \frac{F}{d^2} \$

\$\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \quad = \quad \frac{d^2}{F}\$

\$F \quad = \quad \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} q_2 E \quad = \quad \frac{d^2}{F} \frac{q_2 q_1}{d^2} \quad = \quad \frac{d^2}{F} \frac{F F}{d^2}\$

\$B \quad = \quad \frac{I_1}{d} \quad = \quad \frac{q_1}{t d} \quad = \quad \frac{F}{t d} \quad = \quad \frac{F / v}{t^2}\$

\$\mu \quad = \quad \frac{t^2}{F}\$

\$F \quad = \quad \mu I_2 B d \quad = \quad \frac{t^2}{F} \frac{q_2}{t} \frac{q_1}{t d} d \quad = \quad \frac{t^2}{F} \frac{F}{t} \frac{F}{t d} d\$

\$c \quad = \quad \sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 \mu_0}} \quad = \quad \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{F} \frac{F}{t^2}} \quad = \quad \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{t^2}} = \frac{d}{t}\$

https://tok.fandom.com/wiki/Template:Electromagnetism_header

Comment: ohms / (sec^2) has units of  1 / (C t) where C is capacitance and t is time.  Does that help?  (impedance is measured in ohms.)  Of note: 1 Farad = 1 second/ohm and 1 Henry = 1 (ohm*second).

Comment: I'm really sorry to have troubled you. It should have been force per velocity per time squared.

Comment: In my defense wolfram alpha said it was mechanical impedance

Comment: If you share the equation and context where you encountered this, it will be easier to answer.